# How to make UITabbar black?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I tried two way to make `UITabbar` black but neither way works. Any idea why?

```
tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: Use `tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
    tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in a non-coding way, and are using storyboard.

Select your `UITabBarController`. Next select your `UITabBar` inside the `UITabBarController`. As shown:

[image]

Now on your right, select the attributes inspector. And select the bar tint color to what you want.

[image]